# Unexpected lambda behavior C++ with Arduino

Tags: c++, lambda, arduino

I'm trying to understand why the second millis() timer does not work as I would expect.  Is there some encapsulation that I don't understand while using lambdas?  Or maybe I'm just not seeing something!

the second expression in loop() does not print, the first does:

```
unsigned long timerVal = 0;
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();
}
void loop() 
{
  [&timerVal](unsigned long currentTime){if(currentTime - timerVal > 1000UL) {Serial.println("Hello World"); timerVal += 1000UL;}}(millis());
  [&timerVal](){if(millis() - timerVal > 1000UL) {Serial.println("Why Not Me?"); timerVal += 1000UL;}};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first lambda was called because you called it, the second wasn't called... Add the call `()` to the very end of the lambda.

```
void loop() 
{
  [&timerVal](unsigned long currentTime){if(currentTime - timerVal > 1000UL) {Serial.println("Hello World"); timerVal += 1000UL;}}
   (millis());  //<--call

  [&timerVal](){if(millis() - timerVal > 1000UL) {Serial.println("Why Not Me?"); timerVal += 1000UL;}}
     (); /// now, we call... :-)
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I guess part B of my anticipated problems was true.